# preventing text from reaching the right side of the textarea, reserving space for vertical scroll bar, which will not move the text when appears

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a textarea which when typing some text into, after so many line you get a vertical scroll bar which moves text a bit to the left because it needs space for itself.

How can I reserve that area on the right side of textarea where the scroll bar will appear so that nothing will be written there?

I have tried applying `padding-right` to textarea but it moves the scroll bar itself to the left.

Comment: Don't you mean a vertical scroll bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an exact answer, but you might want to go completely scrollbar-less - 
[Autosize jQuery](https://plugins.jquery.com/autosize/)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but you could force the scrollbar to be there always using css:

```
.mytextarea {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

This is not fully cross browser compatible as it does not work with some older browsers, but it is pretty good.

You could optionally always show both scrollbars, but I find that tacky:

```
.mytextarea {
    overflow: scroll;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a  `<textarea>` inside of a `div.`  Have the `div` set to `overflow:auto`, and make the `textarea`'s width about 15px smaller than that of the `div`.  Use some javascript magic to change the height of the textarea as the user types in it, so that it gets taller (plenty of sites do this so it's definitely doable.)  Once the `textarea` is taller than the `div`, the scrollbar appears in the `div` without resizing the `textarea`.  Scrolling should behave fine because your focus is still within the `div` you're scrolling.

I feel like there's a better way to word this answer but it should work.

Comment: Note that this will keep the scrollbar hidden until it's needed, and the `div` reserves the extra space for it in the page's structure so everything stays put once the scrollbar appears.